# Photoshop like Grid/Guidelines with JQuery, Html 5

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas

I'm looking for Photoshop like grid & Guidelines with JQuery. Is there any plugin for this ? Or is there any way to create such dragable/movable guides over Html 5 page.

[image]

**UPDATE / ANSWER**

Here is working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2RRw/5/) [ Thanks to [**Xenethyl**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555322/xenethyl) ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there aren't any plugins available for something like this. Creating said functionality should be pretty straight-forward, though.

jQuery UI has a `draggable` property that you can assign, so I would approach this by just creating divs that have dimensions equal to either `100% width, 1px height` or `1px width, 100% height`. You can have your ruler (or some other tray to pull the guides out of) on the edges of your work area, and when the user clicks in the hot spot area they end up grabbing a hidden guideline. If they drag the guideline back to the tray area, the guide is hidden and/or destroyed.

Since you can only create one guideline at a time (following the Photoshop approach), I'd suggest pre-creating both a vertical and a horizontal guideline and hiding them under your ruler or whatever hot spot you're using for guideline creation. That way you can propagate the mousedown event to the hidden guide relatively easily and you don't have to worry about transferring the event to a DOM element that has not yet been created (ie. I would avoid creating guides as needed; always have one ready to go).

I would probably handle the hiding of the guidelines using `z-indexing`, but you could also play around with opacity and background color options if either would be easier to implement given your application.

Comment: Thanks Xenethyl for your reply.. I'll definitely give a try !

Comment: Hey Xenethyl, Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/QuadCodes/h2RRw/5/embedded/result/

Comment: @MANnDAaR Awesome! That looks like it works pretty well! Depending on your requirements, you can add in a callback after the user drops the guideline (initially) to create another one so you always have one ready to go on the edge. Very nice! :)

Comment: Hey Xenethyl, I tried using .clone().prependTo method in order to create another new grid on the edge.. But then it is not allowing me to move previous lines. I can only move newly created lines. Here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QuadCodes/h2RRw/6/ Can you help me with this ? Thanks.

Comment: @MANnDAaR Sure, I went ahead and implemented what I think you're looking for here: http://jsfiddle.net/h2RRw/12/. The idea is that you have a stationary `X` and `Y` guide that you can't grab in the background. Then, you keep track of which guide was most recently created. If an `X` or `Y` guide stops moving, we check to see if it's the latest one (ie. it started on the edge). If so, we create another. You'll probably want to check the stop position to make sure the user doesn't move the guide back to the edge (ex. they decide not to keep the guide), and if so prevent the creation of another.